# Approximating the integral $\int_t^{t+h} f(s)\,ds$ by $f(t)h$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose $f$ is a continuous real-valued function, and $h>0$.

Does the following condition hold 
$$
\int_t^{t+h} f(s)\,ds\sim f(t)h
$$
and if so is this due to mid value rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea here is that if $h$ is sufficiently small, then, on the interval $[t,t+h]$, $f(s)$ is essentially constant. Treating $f(s)$ as a constant, you end up with $$\displaystyle\int_{t}^{t+h} f(s) ds \approx f(s) \displaystyle\int_{t}^{t+h} ds = f(s) \left( (t+h) - t \right) \Longrightarrow \displaystyle\int_{t}^{t+h} f(s) ds  \approx f(s) h$$

I'm not sure if there's a more formal way of reaching this approximation, but I have seen this type of derivation used in examples from physics.

Comment: I agree. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: There is no assumption that $f$ is continuous. Did @sara forget it?

Comment: right, but it is assumed

Answer (score 1):

You could also see this as a first-order Taylor's approximation. Let $F(t)=\int_c^tf(s)ds$ be an antiderivative of $f$, then
$$
\int_{t}^{t+h}f(s)ds=F(t+h)-F(t)\approx hF'(t)=hf(t).
$$
One advantage of this is that it makes it clear on how to improve the approximation. For example, if $f'$ exists at $t$, then the second-order approximation is 
$$
hF'(t)+\frac{1}{2}F''(t)h^2=hf(t)+\frac{1}{2}f'(t)h^2.
$$